# php mailer redirect to blank page after clicking on send button

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I just want to know what is the reason of my instance.

My code looks like this:

```
<form action="php/contact.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contact_send" />

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label for="contact:name">Full Name *</label>
                                            <input required type="text" value="" class="form-control" name="contact[name][required]" id="contact:name">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label for="contact:email">E-mail Address *</label>
                                            <input required type="email" value="" class="form-control" name="contact[email][required]" id="contact:email">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <label for="contact:phone">Phone</label>
                                            <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" name="contact[phone]" id="contact:phone">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <label for="contact:subject">Subject *</label>
                                            <input required type="text" value="" class="form-control" name="contact[subject][required]" id="contact:subject">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <label for="contact:message">Message *</label>
                                            <textarea required maxlength="10000" rows="6" class="form-control" name="contact[message]" id="contact:message"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </fieldset>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> SEND MESSAGE</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>


<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

require 'http://***.net/php/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

 $mail = new PHPMailer;


$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;


$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';


$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

 $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');


submission
$mail->Port = 587;


$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';


$mail->SMTPAuth = true;


$mail->Username = "****@gmail.com";


$mail->Password = "****";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('kontakt@****', '');

//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('', 'John Doe');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images                     
to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));

//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent!";
}
$headers = 'From: '.$name."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
header('Location: http://***.net/kontakt.html');
```

I am really confused, I tried everything with that but still without any succes. My hosting also did not tell me anything about this problem.
I tried with send mail function but the case is the same.

I will be gratefull for any answer.

Comment: you can try `header('Location: kontakt.html'); exit;`

Comment: `require 'http://....` that for one thing and if it's what you're really using, should be a path and not a URL.

Comment: we also don't know if you're using any of the inputs as arrays.

Comment: Even when I am using path not url the result is the same ! Blank page all time :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting bitten by the misuse of the header() function. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Things like blank lines and your `echo` statements, or indeed, who knows what goes on in the `require`d file, are causing your call to redirect with a `header` to fail.